# Hanging a 65" flat screen tv

Tags: wood

I want to hang the tv above the fireplace. I was able to remove the paneling on the side of the fireplace what I found was the 2 out side 2x4 were mounted on edge but the other 3 were mounted flat, this is over a 6' span. Will the flat 2x4 be able to hold the tv

Comment: Mounting a tv over a fireplace is often a bad idea...usually puts it too high up for comfortable viewing, and the extra heat reduces the tv's lifespan.  Doesnt mean dont do it, but keep those facts in mind.

Comment: How much does the TV weight? Are mounting it on one stud or two?

Answer (score 1):

You will not have problems mounting the TV if it is under 150 lbs and into 2 or more studs.  Use proper screws and mounting system/plates.

Comment: ...but bear in mind that he's looking at mounting the TV to the flat side of these "studs," not on the edge, where the greater width would provide greater strength. Still, he's probably fine in this case.

Comment: Yep, I took note of that.